# How to disable swipe Right in recylerview?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain recyclerview with adapter which populate some data in recyclerview.When i swipe left it delete item at that position. But problem is that i don't want swipe right i only want swipe left. How do i do that

code:-

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
                adapter.removeItem(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

            Bitmap icon;
            if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){

                View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
                float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
                float width = height / 3;

                if(dX < 0){
                    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                    RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(),(float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                    c.drawRect(background,p);
                    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_delete);
                    RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                    c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
                }
            }
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(notificationList);
```

Comment: read `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` documentation

Comment: I already read but pls let me know how to disable swipe right only

Comment: so what does the second paragraph say? also, when using `SimpleCallback` you can pass your `swipeDirs` directly - so there is no need in overriding any methods

Answer (score 3):

Have you noticed your first line of code that this code will be fire when you swipe either LEFT or RIGHT

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
```

so Remove the RIGHT direction Code

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
```

and this will be works like charm :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback
            (0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT ) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {





        }
    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override this method in `ItemTouchHelper.Callback`:

```
@Override
public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
    final int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.END; // or RIGHT
    return makeMovementFlags(0, swipeFlags);
}
```